# Azure SSO login for external users

Tags: azure, single-sign-on

I'm developing system where any user can login through Microsoft Azure SSO.
I have done following

- Create B2C tenant (Initially tried B2B)
- Create enterprise application
- Set "AzureADandPersonalMicrosoftAccount" for "signInAudience"
- Setup SSO with SAML using "https://simplesamlphp.org/"

Now everything is working fine for my account. But if I trying with other personal user (which I haven't added as guest user in my tenant), then it returns error

```
User account 'user@domain.com' from identity provider 'live.com' does not exist in tenant 'xxxx' 
and cannot access the application in that tenant. 
The account needs to be added as an external user in the tenant first. 
Sign out and sign in again with a different Azure Active Directory user account.
```

I want any personal Microsoft user can login through SSO (without adding it as guest user in tenant).

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

***I tried to reproduce the same in my environment and got the below results:***

Please **note** that, if you are creating Enterprise Application in Azure AD b2c Tenant it will be authenticated via Azure Active Directory only not Azure AD b2c.

[image]

When I tried to login through Personal Account, I got the **same error** as below:

[image]

> **As Enterprise Applications authenticate via Azure AD, it is not
> possible to authenticate users with personal Microsoft accounts
> without adding them as Guest Users.**

The only approach is that you add them as Guest users and login to ***SAML SSO without invitation.***

*Go to Azure Portal -> External Identities -> External collaboration settings -> Enable guest self-service sign up via user flows*

[image]

**On the left blade**, *Click on User flows -> New User Flow*,

[image]

Once the user flow gets created successfully, *click on the user flow, select applications and **add your application*** like below:

[image]

**And try signing to your application with Microsoft Personal Account.**