# Using Azure as SSO login just like Google

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory, single-sign-on

I have setup Google as a way for my customers to login to my web app. They just click on the google icon on my login page, and they get logged in.

I want to do the same with Azure.
The problem is that the customers users are member of another tenant in Azure than my tenant, and Azure just gives me an error.
The error is:
User account 'xxx' from identity provider 'customer.com' does not exist in tenant 'My webapp' and cannot access the application (Web app) in that tenant. The account needs to be added as an external user in the tenant first.

However, I have many hundreds of customers, and I cannot add all of their users to my tenant. That's thousands of users.

Is there any way to do Azure SSO login, the same way as Google SSO login, just allowing anyone with a valid Azure login to get in to my webapp?

(of course I do checks that verify that the google/azyre login is a match with an existing account in my system)

I am using Laravel with socialite for the Google SSO, and setup the same for Azure with the socialite azure driver.

Google works, Azure does not.
However, Azure works for the users that are a member of my tenant, just not for other tenants.
I also tried the solution suggested here: [Azure SSO login for external users](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73931392/azure-sso-login-for-external-users) , but that did nothing, same result.

Comment: You need to create a new application in Azure AD and make it multi-tenant. Customers will then need to approve their access when they sign in.

Comment: Azure B2C? Have you looked into it?

Answer (score 0):

I changed the tenant id in the Socialite config to "common" (before it was my own tenant id). This fixed the issue and now any tenant can login.